# Getting tkinter Messagebox at top of the screen in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, messagebox

I need message box to be displayed on the top of the screen. So, I tried:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
root = Tk()

top_box = Toplevel(root)

messagebox.showerror("title","message",parent=top_box)

root.mainloop()
```

The result I got is: taskbar gives attraction that something new has been open.
[image]

> But it doesn't show on the screen. (Should be visible first/ Priorty to be given to it..)

Comment: Does your windows let you execute this code directly on the command prompt? If so, in case your program is crashing silently, you might find some error report in commandline's output if you test your program directly through a command prompt.

Comment: @SebasSBM No, it doesn't show any error in command-line's output...

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me on windows 10:

```py
import tkinter
root = tkinter.Tk()

root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
root.withdraw()
tkinter.messagebox.showerror("title", "message", parent=root)

root.destroy()
```

I was able to/had to simplify some things.

Because of `root.withdraw`, the window does not appear in the taskbar.

I would also like to credit the person who made [this post](https://python-forum.io/thread-26709-post-114036.html#pid114036), I have seen many solutions that include `-topmost 1`, but that was the first solution that used the `parent` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The `messagebox` module uses [platform native functions on Windows](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1062) to create its dialogs. It works independently of any `Toplevel` widgets. If you want to create a custom error dialog using a `Toplevel` you can do so, and you can move it to the top of the window manager using `Toplevel.lift(self)`.

There is no option to make the message boxes appear on top of all other windows. The only way is to make a custom error window with a `Toplevel`. Something like this should do the trick, provided that you create a `tk.Tk` somewhere else in your program:

```
import tkinter as tk


class Error(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, message):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        tk.Label(self, text=message).grid(row=0, column=0)
        tk.Button(self, command=self.destroy, text="OK").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.lift()  # Puts Window on top
        self.grab_set()  # Prevents other Tkinter windows from being used


def showerror(string):
    Error(string)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    w = tk.Tk()
    showerror("Help!")
    w.mainloop()
```